# 2D Texture rendering blinky in Safari, fine in Chrome / Firefox

Tags: javascript, safari, webgl

Live site here:

https://handoffgame.herokuapp.com/

It's being rendered with:

- http://handoffgame.herokuapp.com/lib/blit/surface.js
- http://handoffgame.herokuapp.com/lib/blit/sprite.js
- http://handoffgame.herokuapp.com/lib/blit/web-gl.js

I wish I had a more specific question, but there are no errors and Safari appears to think it's working fine... but the textures blink in and out. Right now I'm trying to figure out what types of things could cause such an issue, since I have no idea.

Comment: No safari at hand but maybe [Z-Fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) ? Btw. your code is very imperformant, one should aim to have as few state changes as possible. You could easily render all your sprites using one buffer, heck even using one draw call.

Comment: It's designed to be general. Just a utility to stamp out sprites with no requirements about which textures they're using or where they are etc. I'm open to recommendations for making it more performant, but not at the expense of simplicity or generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Safari won't allow you to `drawImage` beyond the bounds of the image, and some imprecision with pixels was leading to overdraw of a little less than a pixel.

I fixed it by checking the width and height bounds of the image before drawing from it.